# couldn't find file 'twitter-bootstrap-static/bootstrap'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems

I "bundle install" git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git.
And then, rails generate bootstrap:install static.  Those two command ran fine, but I get this error in my local server.

---

> Sprockets::FileNotFound in Pages#home
>
> Showing
>   /Users/~~~/Dropbox/TODOAPP/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
>   where line #5 raised:
>
> couldn't find file 'twitter-bootstrap-static/bootstrap'   (in
>   /Users/~~~/Dropbox/TODOAPP/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css:2)

Extracted source (around line #5):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODOAPP</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
```

Rails.root: /Users/~~~/Dropbox/TODOAPP

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1375052121185580577_70165167901400'
Request

Parameters:

None
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None

application.css

```css
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your application.css file?

Comment: I just added the file above!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things you should try:

1. Try running rake assets:clean assets:precompile
2. Try running the command again
3. Restart your web server

It seems a file from bootstrap is not being imported. If the above does not work I would also try removing the bootstrap files manually, and then adding them manually.